Countable-dimensional Schur's lemma for countable fields
Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A$ be an associative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra. Suppose $M$ is a simple $A$-module s.t. $\dim_{\mathbb{K}} M$ is countable. Is that true that $\operatorname{End}_A(M)\simeq \mathbb{K}$?
If $\mathbb{K}$ is uncountable, then the statement is true, but the proof that I know uses that $\dim_{\mathbb{K}}\mathbb{K}(x)$ is uncountable in that case.
So what if $\mathbb{K}$ is countable?
Thanks for paying attention.

I may be missing something, but what about $M=A=K(x)$?

@Aphelli sure, thank you

I am turning my comment into an answer.
Take $A=M=\mathbb{K}(x)$. Then $M$ is a $A$-vector space of dimension one, hence a simple $A$-module. Moreover, $M$ has countable dimension over $\mathbb{K}$. Finally, $\mathrm{End}_A(M)=A=\mathbb{K}(x)$ is not equal to $\mathbb{K}$.
